# merge csv files - python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, jupyter-notebook

I am using a for loop to merge csv files on jupyter notebook, however my result returns a list instead of a dataframe. Could someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
files = ['babd_light_z1.csv','babd_light_z2.csv','babd_light_z3.csv']
data = []
for f in files:
     data.append(pd.read_csv(f))

type(data) # returns  list
```

Comment: Change `data = []` to `data = pd.DataFrame()` and reassign `data` in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `pd.concat(data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)` outside your loop to merge your csv files as in:

```
files = ['babd_light_z1.csv', 'babd_light_z2.csv', 'babd_light_z3.csv']

data = []

for f in files:
    data.append(pd.read_csv(f))

df = pd.concat(data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

`type(df)` should return `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
combined = pd.combine(data, axis=0)
```